# Creating a meal Cost calculator C#

Tags: c#

[image]

I'm trying to create a Meal Cost Calculator using C#.
Here is my current code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    const double TAX_RATE = .076;
    const double EXTRA_DISCOUNT = .1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void tiplistBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((lessThanButton.Checked == true) && (moreThanButton.Checked == false)) ;
        {
            int selectedIndex = tiplistBox1.SelectedIndex;
            switch (selectedIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }           
    }

    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int mealCost = int.Parse(mealCostBox1.Text);
        double tax = (mealCost * TAX_RATE) + mealCost;
        double disc = (tax * EXTRA_DISCOUNT);
        double tipRate = (tax - disc);
        double totalCost = (tipRate);
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 1;

        if ((lessThanButton.Checked == true) && (moreThanButton.Checked == false))
        {
            tiplistBox1.Items.Add("");
            for (count = 10; count <= 35; count += 5)
                tiplistBox1.Items.Add("Tip Rate: " + count + "%");
            count++;
        }
    }      

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 1;

        if ((lessThanButton.Checked == false) && (moreThanButton.Checked == true))
        {
            tiplistBox1.Items.Add("");
            for (count = 15; count <= 35; count += 5)
                tiplistBox1.Items.Add("Tip Rate: " + count + "%");
            count++;
        }         
    }
}
```

The user must enter the amount of the meal.
Then the user selects a radio button that asks how many people ate. (one RB is for less than 6 and the other is for more than 6.) this button is used in order to give tip rates which are displayed in tiplistBox1 (if <6 ppl = 10,15,20,25,30,35, if >6 ppl 15,20,25,30,35) The user must also identify if there is any type of discount, which is selected from checking one of three boxes (student, military or senior) if either one is selected a 10% discount is added. Once all is selected the calculate button is supposed to take the mealCost add the TAX_RATE, take any discounts off and if a tip rate is selected from the tiplistBox1 options, add the tipRate then give the amount due.

Right now, my project isn't complete, there are a few issues, first of all, as you can see, I'm not using the If,Else statements, I'm required to use switch statements, when I'm running the program from the start I'm getting the tipRate's to display correctly for example, if I select the RB that is <6 people, then the tipRates shown are 10,15,20,25,30,35. If instead, from the start I select RB that is >6 people then the tipRates 15,20,25,30,35 are shown. That's good, but when I try to switch the RB within the ongoing program the TipRates get added underneath the first set of tipRates
, also since I'm using switch statements, if I select either of the RB, the displayed tipRates don't match up, meaning if I create a case 1: in one instance it shows 10% but in another is shows 15%, which messes with the calculation process.

I need help!
How can I ensure that the tipRate selected will make sence in the calculation.
for example if in case 1: it shows 15% but only does the math for 10% tipRate.

Comment: Thanks to madreflection  I was able to fix the issue of the listbox not clearing the results. Now how do I call the percentages created on the listbox and use them to figure out the amount due.

Comment: This exceeds the scope of the original question and deserves to be a separate question. Editing the question for a new issue reduces visibility for future users with the same issue.  Asking a separate question allows you to narrow the focus on the new issue and get fresh eyes on the topic. Also, please [accept helpful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as you go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...but when I try to switch the RB within the ongoing program the TipRates get added underneath the first set of tipRates

That's because you need to clear the list before adding the new set of rates to the list.

Call `tiplistBox1.Items.Clear()` before calling `tiplistBox1.Items.Add("")`.

Comment: *face palm, I kept adding it to the end... so it would delete it immediately, I never thought about adding it before.